# Redshift - Getting full list of grants for users

Tags: permissions, amazon-redshift, sql-grant

As you probably noticed, Redshift is a pain to extract permissions from. Handling arrays raises all sorts of errors...

Because I am managing the security of Redshift with an automated program, and it relies on both groups and user grants, I need to know how the user got the privilege: through group or custom user grant.

Using all the online resources, I have created a view that shows all of the above. I know this is not a question, but it was the only way I found of sharing the code and "giving back" to the community...

Does anyone have anything to add, improvements to suggest?

```
  SELECT nspname schema_name    
        , relname table_name
        , pg_group.groname user_group
        , pg_user.usename  username

        , case when charindex('U',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(nspacl, '|'),usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then 'user'
                when charindex('U',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(nspacl, '|'),groname,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then 'group'
          end                                                                                                                   as schema_usage

        , case when charindex('C',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(nspacl, '|'),usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then 'user'
                when charindex('C',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(nspacl, '|'),groname,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then 'group'
          end                                                                                                                   as schema_obj_create

         , case 
            when charindex('r',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then 'user'
            when charindex('r',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),groname,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then 'group'
           end                                                                                                                  as table_select

         , case 
            when charindex('w',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then 'user'
            when charindex('W',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),groname,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then 'group'
           end                                                                                                                  as table_update 
         , case 
            when charindex('a',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then 'user'
            when charindex('a',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),groname,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then 'group'
           end                                                                                                                   as table_insert 
         , case 
            when charindex('d',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then 'user'
            when charindex('d',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),groname,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then 'group'
           end                                                                                                                   as table_delete 
         , case 
            when charindex('x',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then 'user'
            when charindex('x',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),groname,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then 'group'
           end                                                                                                                   as table_reference

FROM pg_user 
left join pg_group
    on array_to_string(grolist, '|') like '%'||pg_user.usesysid||'%'
inner join pg_namespace
    on array_to_string(nspacl, '|') like '%'||usename||'%'
        or array_to_string(nspacl, '|') like '%group '||groname||'%'
left join pg_class AS objs
        on relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid
            and (array_to_string(relacl, '|') like '%'||usename||'%'
                    or array_to_string(relacl, '|') like '%group '||groname||'%')
```

Comment: *but it was the only way I found of sharing the code* - the correct way would be a self-answered question. You ask a question and add your own answer to it.